# Does anyone possibly know why the latency of my cloud debugger api is so high?

Tags: api, latency, google-cloud-debugger

Does anyone know how to identify the issue and fix it?

[image]

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more details about this app? With this amount of information it's just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

The latency does not look like a problem.

The Cloud Debugger API latency metrics will include [ListActiveBreakpoint](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/api/reference/rest/v2/controller.debuggees.breakpoints/list) rpcs that deliberately stay open for a long period of time in order to reduce polling frequency.  Essentially, the rpc will return when there is a new breakpoint set or when the request times out (at roughly 50 seconds, based on your screenshot).

The Cloud Debugger API requests occur in the background so the latency should not affect your system in any meaningful way.